# How to refresh a component in React?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my header component:

```
class HeaderComponent extends  React.Component {

    render() {

        const  isUserLoggedIn=AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()
        console.log(isUserLoggedIn)
        return(
            <header>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <div><a  href="http://www.in28minutes.com" className="navbar-brand">in28minutes</a></div>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        {isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/welcome/in28minutes">Home</Link></li>}
                        {isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/todos">Todos</Link></li>}
                    </ul>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav navbar-collapse justify-content-end ">
                        {!isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/login"  >login</Link></li>}
                        { isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/logout" onClick={AuthenticationService.logout}>logout</Link></li>}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

As soon as I click on the login button, I want to re-render the header component. Any suggestions? I tried `window.location.reload(true)` but after doing it, the JWT token is being removed from the session. I want an alternative solution for `window.location.reload(true)`.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: You might want to look into state and state management. Using state, you could automatically update the component based on whether the user is logged in, which I presume is what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I thank stack overflow for giving this wonderful platform so that I could ask my questions and solve my problems .

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is when I click on login button the Home , Todos and logout menu is displayed and when i click on logout button again only login button is displayed

Comment: I followed all the [solutions](https://shouts.dev/how-to-refresh-a-component-and-page-in-react) but none of them really worked for me . Thats why I am asking this question and I want to solve this problem in a different way . May be refreshing a part of web page will do the trick .

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please ask original problem.